# Python sql with 4 table

Tags: python, django

Please help me how to use query in restframework (I dont want to use raw query, if this question no idea I will use raw query instead), I'm new to python and django restframework!

My data : tbl product:

This is my views.py

```
class Transaction_listlView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
        queryset = Transaction.objects.filter(user_id = user).exclude(deleted_at__isnull = False)
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(queryset, context={'fields': ['transaction_id','user_id','address','phone_number','status','total']}, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
        transaction = TransactionVersion.objects.filter(transaction__pk = pk).filter(transaction__user_id = user)
        serializer = TransactionVersionSerializer(transaction, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class FieldMixin(object):
    def get_field_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
        field_names = self.context.get('fields', None)
        if field_names:
            return field_names
        return super(FieldMixin, self).get_field_names(*args, **kwargs)


class TransactionSerializer(FieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer, object):
    transaction_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = '__all__'



class TransactionVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.IntegerField(source='version_id')
    class Meta:
        model = TransactionVersion
        fields = ('product' , 'quantity')
```

and repsone I want for details transaction (user must login to get transaction):

```
{
version_id{
   product_name:
   size:
   color
}
quantity
```

This is my data :

```
product table : id, name, des, rate
transaction table: id, address ......, user_id
transaction_version table: id, quantity, transaction_id, version_id
version table: id, size, color ....., product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) and [Writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).Please add model classes to your question. Because I can't write result serializer classes without them

Comment: I aready read all above and get a lot of information now, and this time I stuck in def destroy, could you please follow this and help me ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286007/cant-use-def-destroy-viewset-viewset-soft-delete