# Can't use def destroy viewset.viewset (soft delete)

Tags: python, django

I got this err, i already searched and get this resolved and already add date_time variable but cant and I just want to use viewset instead, please help me solve :(

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'transaction' into field. Choices are: address, created_at, deleted_at, id, notification, phone_number, status, total, transactionvariant, updated_at, user, user_id
```

here is my def destroy(views.py):

```
class TransactionView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
        queryset = Transaction.objects.filter(user_id=user).exclude(deleted_at__isnull=False)
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
        transaction = TransactionVariant.objects.filter(transaction__pk=pk).filter(transaction__user_id=user)
        serializer = TransactionVariantSerializer(transaction, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        date_time = datetime.now()
        # user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
        transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(transaction__pk=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(transaction, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and my serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name',)

class VariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # product = ProductSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Variant
        fields = ('name', 'size', 'color', 'price', 'image_link',)

class TransactionVariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variant = VariantSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    # products = serializers.VariantSerializer(variant)
    # products = serializers.(fields='variant')
    class Meta:
        model = TransactionVariant
        fields = ('quantity','variant')


class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    transaction_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
    # product = ProductSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    # variant = VariantSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        # fields = ('transaction_id','user_id','status','total','created_at')
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using `transaction__pk`. The double underscore is to follow a relationship, so this assumes you are looking for the pk field on the model related via the `transaction` ForeignKey. But you don't have a ForeignKey, and the pk is directly on the Transaction model. Just use:

```
Transaction.objects.filter(pk=pk)...
```

Comment: I edited but still the same err, i think the solution is in serializer.py or model, datetime ect.. but I cant figure it out because I'm new in python :(

Comment: You need to show the full traceback, plus your models.

Comment: @ViếtPhúTrần show your full traceback after edit code from `Transaction.objects.filter(transaction__pk=pk)...` to `Transaction.objects.filter(pk=pk)...`

Comment: thanks Andrey, I also ask my friends for solution and he he explain me the 'pk' variable <3, could you read my new answer on the top @Andrey

Answer (score 0):

I already fix it! and here is my new code:

```
def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        # transaction_id = TransactionVariant.objects.filter(transaction__pk=transactionvariant.transaction__pk)
        # transaction_variant = TransactionVariant.objects.select_related('transaction').get(id=1)
        # print("hihihhihiihihi",transaction_variant)

        date_time = datetime.now()
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
        transaction = TransactionVariant.objects.filter(transaction__pk=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)
        transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(id=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)
        print("adsfasdf", transaction)
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(transaction, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, many=True)
```

but after that i got new error when using url (http://localhost:8000/api/transactions/3/) METHOD delete, my database of course has update the deleted field for both transaction and transaction_variant but show this log :
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

you can reference my serializer.py from the top